# where date between start of year and end of last day before one month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have problem with my query. I don't know how to calculate data for date. I want to display date from early month to one month before.

For example, this year. From jan-sept. Not include for this month. I have problem with this condition

```
and mhn.trh_masuk between add_months(Last_day(sysdate) + 1, -10) and add_months(Last_day(sysdate) + 0, -2)
```

This my oracle sql:

```
select DISTINCT
count(mhn.id_mohon) ide,
add_months(Last_day(sysdate)+1,-10) datejan,
add_months(Last_day(sysdate)+0,-2) onemonthbeforenow,
ku.nama u4
from
mohon mhn, kod_urusan ku, kod_caw kc
where
 mhn.kod_urusan = ku.kod(+)
and mhn.kod_caw = kc.kod(+)
AND KU.AKTIF = 'Y'
AND KU.KOD_JABATAN= 2
and mhn.trh_masuk between add_months(Last_day(sysdate)+1,-10) and add_months(Last_day(sysdate)+0,-2)
and (mhn.kod_caw = :p_kod_caw or :p_kod_caw is null)
and (mhn.kod_urusan in ('PBMT','PBMMK'))    
group by ku.nama
```

Anyone got any idea for other formula to this solution?

Comment: So, you want the data from `start of the year` to the `last day of previous month`?

Comment: yes @Ramblin'Man,Do you know how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this,

```
AND mhn.trh_masuk BETWEEN trunc(SYSDATE,'YEAR') AND last_day(add_months(TRUNC(SYSDATE), -1)) + .99999
```

Comment: `TRUNC(last_day(add_months(SYSDATE, -1)))` will give Sep 30, 2013 00:00:00. hence last day's records won't be selected.

Comment: @Ramblin'Man, thanks for pointing out the issue, I've modified the answer.

Comment: @dba,tq very much.your answer so helpful.:)

Comment: You might more elegantly use:  " < Trunc(Sysdate,'Month')"